# jQuery plugin: crud table plugin which support file upload option

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was using jtable plugin. It was working fine until i meet the need of uploading a file or multiple file(mostle image) in my form. I researched and found out that jtable doesn't have this feature. Is there any jquery plugin which support multiple file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not going to find image upload functionality bundled with a jquery grid plugin since they are separate concerns. I'd suggest building/including a file upload plugin/ajax function on Add/Edit of your row, then storing it with that rows data or json object.

For a really advanced jQuery table plugin, I typically steer torwards http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html jqGrid, though it's overkill on most projects.

For a nice upload plugin that handles multiple files, check out http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

You should be able to hook the upload plugin to your grid row data.

Comment: can i use jquery file upload plugin inside my jtable??? i.e if i click add new record button, i will get a form in jtable, can i use upload file option inside that form????

Comment: Yes, you should be able to define what's in your add record form and implement the plugin there.

Answer (score 1):

hi you may use Uploadify on jtable.
you may refer on the steps made in the last post by me (une6)

https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/321

took a while to figure out, but i hope it'll help you too

Answer (score 1):

just Followe these steps
1.add this code  to jtable javascript code below field
" image_upload: {
                        title: 'P. Image',
                        list:true,
                        width: '20%',

```
                     display: function (data) {
                  return '<div id='+ data.record.PersonId + '><form id="form'+ data.record.PersonId +'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajaximage.php"><input type="file" name="photoimg" id="'+ data.record.PersonId +'" class="upload"/><input type="hidden"  value="'+ data.record.PersonId +'"/></form></div><div id="preview'+ data.record.PersonId +'"></div>';
                       }"
```

in "data.record.PersonId"  PersonId is return by jtable from database

1. download script from
   http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html
2. unzip the folder
   copy paste a file jquery.form.js from and include this file to you page
3. add this code to header

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
       $('.upload').live('change', function()          { 
          var id=this.id;
              $("#preview"+id).html('');
           $("#preview"+id).html('<img src="img/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#form"+id).ajaxForm({
                   target: '#preview'+id
       }).submit();

       });
   });
   ```
4. make folder name uploads to store your file or customize it to ajaximage.php
5. copy paste loader.gif from unzip directory to your directory
   and enjoy